How to remove old Github account from Visual Studio Code
I connected my github account with my vs code , but it got suspended unknowingly , still then i made another account on another email and tried to connect with vs code , every time i tried to connect it with vs code and push the code and showed my previous account details and says that you can't push the code your account is suspended ,
for temporary usage I'm using git hub desktop to commit and push code which is working fine , but vs code direct commit or commit using commands is not working even though i uninstalled and reinstalled several times it always tries to commit into that previous account !!
kindly give me a solution
for temporary usage I'm using git hub desktop to commit and push code which is working fine , but vs code direct commit or commit using commands is not working even though i uninstalled and reinstalled several times it always tries to commit into that previous account !!
